# Reading value of hiddenfield after javascript on server side

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a problem with asp:hiddenfield, when I change its value in client side and wants to get it in server side , it gives me null...
here is client side code :

```
function pageLoad() {
        var gV = $('#<%=HiddenField1.ClientID %>');
        gV.val("1");
}
```

and I want to get the value of hiddenfield in server side code :

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button1.Text = HiddenField1.Value;
    }
```

but the result for text of button is null... why??
thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 1):

After this line:

```
var gV = $('#<%=HiddenField1.ClientID %>').val();
```

`gV` is a string, so `gV.val("1")` doesn't make sense.

Try this:

```
var gV = $('#<%=HiddenField1.ClientID %>');
gV.val("1");
```

Now, that shouldn't cause `HiddenField1.Value` to be null... did you mean empty?

Comment: I just edited my post as you say it... but it still gives me empty... why should I do next?

Comment: Are you sure the `pageLoad` function is executing? Try logging the value.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try with document ready?

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="HiddenField1" />
<script type="text/javascript" 
   src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var gV = $('#<%= HiddenField1.ClientID %>');
        gV.val("1");
    });
</script>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

### Or - Use ScriptManager to call pageLoad

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptManager1"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="HiddenField1" />
<script type="text/javascript" 
  src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad() {
        var gV = $('#<%= HiddenField1.ClientID %>');
        gV.val("1");
    }
</script>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```